# Reading from a file?

Tags: java, servlets

Please help me to do such a thing, let's say we have a text file, **test.txt**, about similar to this:

```
hello hello hello
<link1>http://stackoverflow.com<link1>
```

The first line of text, and the second link enclosed in the `<link1>`. I am printing the contents of the file as follows:

```
 if(myName.equals(name)){

                        InputStreamReader reader  = null;
                        try{


                            File file =  new File("C:\\Users\\ваня\\Desktop\\asksearch\\" + list[i]);

                            reader =  new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");

                            int b;

                            PrintWriter wr =   response.getWriter();
                            wr.print("<html>");
                            wr.print("<head>");
                            wr.print("<title>HelloWorld</title>");
                            wr.print("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">");
                            wr.print("<body>");
                            wr.write("<div>");
                            while((b = reader.read()) != -1) {
                                wr.write((char) b );
                            }
                            wr.write("</div>");
                            wr.write("<hr>");
                            wr.print("</body>");
                            wr.print("</html>");
                            wr.close();


                        }
```

Just a piece of code:

```
while((b = reader.read()) != -1) {
   writer.write((char) b);
}
```

You want to display, the first line of the file itself, and the second line of the file separately

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.print("<html>");
writer.print("<head>");
writer.print("<title>HelloWorld</title>");
writer.print("<body>");
writer.write("<div>");
// then the first line
writer.write("</div>");
writer.write("<div>");
// then the second line
writer.write("</div>");
writer.print("</body>");
writer.print("</html>");
```

Comment: It is called "programming" You store a line in a String, another in another String. To separate lines, you are better off using `BufferedReader` which provides a `readLine` method.

Comment: Can you show a piece of code

Comment: Yes you are right I need to take apart the first and second line

Comment: What are you trying to do in the forst place? This is very werid what you've shown here.

Comment: Well you read my question and comments, I try to bring the first line txt file in the same place (1 div), and the second line in the second div

Comment: You all rekomendutete readline (), but I'm still new, show an example, the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `BufferedReader` for your file:

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
BufferedReader br =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                         new FileInputStream(file), "UTF8"));
```

Use the `readLine` method to read a single line( the first line):

```
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
writer.print("<html>");
writer.print("<head>");
writer.print("<title>HelloWorld</title>");
writer.print("<body>");
writer.write("<div>");
// here to display the text
writer.write(br.readLine());//this will read the first line
writer.write("</div>");

//And for the second line 

writer.write("<div>");
// here to display the text
writer.write(br.readLine());//this will read the next line i.e. second line
writer.write("</div>");
writer.print("</body>");
writer.print("</html>");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but there I was encoded UTF_8, and you do not have it here

Comment: reader =  new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), **UTF-8**);

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend moving away from InputStreamReader as a programmatic type that you'd use the methods of, and use either Scanner or BufferedReader instead... each of these have methods for reading in a single line at a time:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
String line = in.nextLine();
```

or

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line = in.readLine();
```